# US visitor visa question?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

How difficult it is to get a US visitor visa for Indian citizens? I've been living in Hungary for 4 years and I plan to apply for a visitor visa at US embassy in Budapest.

My plans are to visit New York, Los Angeles, Washington, Florida for a couple of weeks in total. I have been previously refused UK tourist visa early 2015.

I own a small business in Hungary, and I work online as freelancer. I make about $1500 a month and have $10K at my disposal.

I plan at staying hotels while in US and wondering how much it would cost me to spend couple of weeks in US.

I have traveled to almost to ALL European countries, have extensive travel history but I'm a bit worried about the visa process. I have never visited US before and I have clear intention of leaving the US as I have strong ties to my home.

Comment: There is no real way to answer that.  These depend on your personal circumstances.

Comment: They can be weird.  Procedurally there is no difference if that's your question.   You really need to apply doing the best you can in order to find out if your profile is acceptable to them.

Comment: In FY 2014 the US [issued](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/NIVDetailTables/FY14NIVDetailTable.pdf) 452,525 B-1/B-2 visas, 1,067 B-1 visas and 747 B-2 visas to Indian citizens. The [adjusted refusal rate](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/refusalratelanguage.pdf) for Indian citizens in that same fiscal year was [19.8%](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY14.pdf). If your application is well put together, you ought to be able to get it.

Comment: Why were you refused the UK visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UK visa refusal should have little to no bearing on your attempt to get a US visa - it is unlikely US immigration officials will even know about it. Staying in the US varies greatly based on where you are staying and the level of comfort you desire. You could easily spend several hundred dollars a night on a hotel in downtown New York City. At the same time, there are cheap solutions if you look for them. I've found private rooms in a hostel in NYC before for about $60/night.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for a B-2 visitor visa. If you're worried about the visa process, this link offers a step-by-step guide for obtaining a visitor visa to the USA: http://www.path2usa.com/visitor-visa-guide, and walks you through each step of the process so you're fully prepared. You shouldn't have a problem getting your B-2 visa as long as you know properly complete the required forms and know what to expect during your interview.
As for the costs of your trip, you can find hotels, hostels, or airbnb.com rooms for pretty inexpensive (some as low as $50 per night) depending on the city.